# How to Check Email Existence on Gmail's SMTP Server (gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com) Using Port 25?

Tags: python, smtp, email-validation

I am attempting to connect to Gmail's SMTP server (gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com) on port 25 using Python to check if an email exists. The provided code includes the connection setup and login, but I am encountering issues. Can someone help me troubleshoot and complete the code for verifying the existence of an email?

```
# Connect to Gmail's SMTP server
with smtplib.SMTP("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25) as server:
    # Send the HELO command
    server.ehlo("gmail.com")
    # Log in to your Gmail account
    server.login(sender_email, sender_password)

    # Send the email commands
    server.sendmail(sender_email, recipient_email, "Subject:”
```